# Canon i-Sensys MF231

Tags: usb, printing, canon, scanner

I install printer driver for this device from Canon official site. All is good, and I can print documents. But with scanner situation is bad. I see in [SANE project page](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON) that Canon MF231 is fully supported but system doesn't see any scanner device from USB.

When I check "lsusb", I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0026 SiGma Micro Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04a9:27d1 Canon, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I enter the command "scanimage -L":

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something 
different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

I read many issues in internet but they very old (since 2007-2011). SANE is fully supported MF231 scan, then why Ubuntu doesn't see scanner of this device?

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo sane-find-scanner` to your question?

Comment: Yes, of course. This is [screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/48SuMlRo3MZcCy)

Comment: Can you get the output if `apt list libsane-dev`

Comment: I get this: `libsane-dev/zesty 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu4 amd64`

Comment: After reinstall system to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3, after `apt list libsane-dev` I get this: sudo apt install libsane-dev (installed). If I enter `apt-list libsane-dev -a` I get: `libsane-dev/xenial-updates,now1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libsane-dev/xenial 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2 amd6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd put this in a comment, but it's slightly involved.

The *sane* project you referenced earlier indicates that the printer that you are trying to use is supported by the `sane-pixma` library - see the reference at http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-pixma.5.html.  The section titled **FILES** has the relevant data.

A package search at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libsane-pixma.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=zesty&arch=any) shows that these files are located in the package `libsane-dev` (and nowhere else) so...

`sudo apt install libsane-dev`

should get you further along in your quest to have your scanner operate properly.

Comment: Yes! You are best Charles! I install **xsane** and after install this packages **(libsane-dev)** scanner work now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have mini question :). I install xsane but they under root. I can't run normally xsane (with default user). I see that user in a group plugdev and scanner. But can't run xsane.  I use `sudo xsane` and scan, but when I save the file I can't open it again. How can I fix it?

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that a *simple scan* is also supported. Just need to run as root. Even then xsane do not need. How to make it run as a normal user?

Comment: I use `ls -l /usr/bin/simple-scan` command, and know I can scan normally under user. But, after save the file (scanned) i also see lock icon on image (file).

Comment: I'm unsure why simple-scan would need a root login - it does not need that on my machines.  The lock icon should just indicate that the file is read-only, although again, I do not have that result.  Perhaps this could be a new question?

Comment: No, I enter the command  `ls -l /usr/bin/simple-scan` simple scan work normally :). Thank you very much again!

Comment: Hello Charles. 

I reinstall system (back to LTS version: Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3). Install Canon driver, then package: `sudo apt install libsane-dev`. No effect for scan. Then I install xsane. And no effect to. 

What can I do?

Comment: @OrkhanOder You might need to start a new question - I don't have anything further that we can try, after reviewing what was done before.

Comment: Why? This is same question. I install Canon official drivers, then install sudo apt install libsane-dev package and xsane. But scanner is not work. Only printer. This is same question.

Comment: Another moment. When I enter command: sudo sane-find-scanner I get:   `# sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.`

Comment: And this: `could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Language Error], product=0x27d1 [Language Error]) at libusb:003:005
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.`

Comment: Since you've reverted to 16.04 and applied the same packages as what was used in the answer, there must be something in the 16.04 kernel which is preventing this from running properly.

Comment: What can I do? Can you help me? Or I must open new question? I don't want open new question, because this is similar problem. Diffirence only about Ubuntu 17.04 and 16.04. I use know 16.04.3 (LTS) version.

Comment: The change back to the older OS complicates things a bit.  I did find a post that suggests that perhaps USB3 is the problem, and that it should be turned off in BIOS.  [https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1100151](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1100151)

Comment: Hm, I fully delete system and install new OS. This is LTS version, I think this is another problem. Maybe I must send you technical information again?

Comment: No - I think you should start a new question, but include in the question that you did get the scanner to work with 17.04, and not with 16.04

Comment: I open new question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/976737/canon-i-sensys-mf231-scanner

Comment: I must only install `libsane` in Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you!