# Canon i-Sensys MF231 scanner

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, canon, scanner

I install printer driver for this device from Canon official site. All is good, and I can print documents. But with scanner situation is bad. I see in [SANE project page](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON) that Canon MF231 is fully supported but system doesn't see any scanner device from USB.

When I check `lsusb`, I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0026 SiGma Micro Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04a9:27d1 Canon, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I enter the command `scanimage -L`:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something 
different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

When I enter: `sudo sane-find-scanner`:

```
 # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
 # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
 # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

 # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make 
 sure that you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

 could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
 could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
 found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Language Error], product=0x27d1 
 [Language Error]) at libusb:003:002
 # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be 
 supported by SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

 # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

 # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary 
 ports can't be detected by this program.
```

And finally this is report `of apt list libsane-dev -a`:

```
 libsane-dev/xenial 1.0.27+git20171029-xenial0 amd64 [can be updated: 
 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1]
 libsane-dev/xenial-updates,now 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 
 amd64 [installed, can be updated: 1.0.27+git20171029-xenial0]
 libsane-dev/xenial 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2 amd64
```

I read many issues in internet but they very old (since 2007-2011). SANE is fully supported MF231 scan, then why Ubuntu 16.04 (.03 LTS) doesn't see scanner of this device?

Note: Before I made such an installation. But on Ubuntu 17.04. Then there is the same problem but the [user suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952169/canon-i-sensys-mf231/) that not enough package: `libsane-dev`. I install it, but no effect.

Thanks.

Comment: you seem very organised; well done. I suggest you talk directly to the SANE guys: join the mailing list http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/sane-devel and tell them the issues; perhaps also install the latest sane, what they call the development issue by adding the Rolf Bensch ppa as from here https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git where there are instructions; please write back for any clarification on them; which version of ubuntu are you running? .. finally .. you used the Canon drivers for the printer?

Comment: Hm, I write him. But I think, I do something wrong. I use Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) and when I install `libsane-dev` in Ubuntu 17.04 scanner work. But in Ubuntu 16.04 no effect. Yes, I install printer driver. This is work fine for printer.

Comment: Answer from SANE: It is fully supported since 2017-04-26.  sane-backends-1.0.27 was
released 2017-05-22. I'd say you have to upgrade your libsane package as you appear to have
1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 installed 'now'.

The output you show is a bit misleading as it shows all the packages
that are *available*, not just the ones that are installed.  Check with

  apt-cache policy libsane. to see what version is installed and upgrade to a 1.0.27 version.

BTW, you don't need libsane-dev, just libsane.

Comment: I check command   apt-cache policy libsane: `libsane:
  Установлен: 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1
  Кандидат:   1.0.27+git20171029-xenial0
  Таблица версий:
     1.0.27+git20171029-xenial0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-git/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 500
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: Can you help me? What know I must do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write to SANE project's mailing list and get answer:

> Hi Orkhan,
>
> Orkhan Guliyev writes:
>
> > Hello.
> >
> > I install printer driver for this device from Canon official site. All
> >     is good, and I can print documents. But with scanner situation is bad. I
> >     see inSANE project page
> >     http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANONthat Canon MF231 is
> >     fully supported but system doesn't see any scanner device from USB.
>
> It is fully supported since 2017-04-26.  sane-backends-1.0.27 was
>   released 2017-05-22, so based on
>
> > [...]
> >     And finally this is report of `apt list libsane-dev -a`:

```
> > libsane-dev/xenial 1.0.27+git20171029-xenial0 amd64 [can be updated: 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1]
> > libsane-dev/xenial-updates,now 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 amd64 [installed, can be updated: 1.0.27+git20171029-xenial0]
> > libsane-dev/xenial 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2 amd64
```

> I'd say you have to upgrade your libsane package as you appear to have
>   1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 installed 'now'.
>
> The output you show is a bit misleading as it shows all the packages
>   that are *available*, not just the ones that are installed.  Check
>   with
>
> apt-cache policy libsane
>
> to see what version is installed and upgrade to a 1.0.27 version.
>
> BTW, you don't need libsane-dev, just libsane.

Know, I only install **`libsane`** in Ubuntu **16.04**, not `libsane-dev` (for Ubuntu 17.04.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to see that this worked for you, and that you were able to get a reply from Canon!

Comment: I understand this to have been a reply from the SANE folks; and I would advise as I did in my first post: add the Rolf Bensch ppa; that the SANE team maintain; that would allow you to install the latest version of sane; please tell us if you have done this yet

Comment: Hello. Interesting moment, I install Ubuntu 18.04 and scan is not work again. I try install "libsane" but get that already installed. libsane and libsane1. 

What's happining?